# jqGrid with Zend Framework (zfdatagrid)

Tags: javascript, jquery, zend-framework, jqgrid

In couple days I couldn't find normal answer. I hope somebody can help me.

I am using jqGrid in my Zend Framework application. I want that grid in my application could be edited inline ([http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:inline_editing](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki%3ainline_editing)). When I am not using ZF and I am writing jqGrid code (java script) by myself - inline editing works ok. But when using ZF class "Bvb_Grid_Deploy_JqGrid" and deploying grid, ZF generates java script by itself. The problem that I couldn't find ZF method to insert js function "onSelectRow" correctly. Tryied to use "$grid->jqAddOnLoad($js);" in ZF controller but this java script code appears not like in example and then grid is not loading normaly at all.
Must be:

```
jQuery().ready(function (){
  jQuery("#jqg_RentAsset").jqGrid(
  {
    height: 250,
     ...
    multiselect: true,
    caption: "Manipulating Array Data",
    onSelectRow: function(id)
    {
      alert(id);
    }
  });
```

But happens:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  jQuery("#jqg_RentAsset").jqGrid(
  {
    onSelectRow: function(id)
    {
      alert(id);
    }
  });
  jQuery("#jqg_RentAsset").jqGrid(
  {
    "height":"250",
      ...
  });
```

Maybe somebody knows what method I must to use in ZF Controller or maybe how differently I need to write java script?

Answer (score 2):

I don't use Zend Framework myself. So my suggestions are common and they are independent for the framework which you use.

In the example below I will show how you can dynamically set `onSelectRow` on the grid to implement inline editing on row selection. I suppose that other required settings like `editable: true` properties of `colModel` and `editurl` option are already exist in the grid. So I show only the setting of `onSelectRow` dynamically.

The first way will be the usage of `setGridParam` to set `onSelectRow` callback. The corresponding [demo](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/SetOnSelectDynamically.htm) use the following code:

```
$(function () {
    var $grid = $("#list"),
        editingRowId,
        myInlineEditingOptions = {
            keys: true,
            oneditfunc: function (id) { editingRowId = id; },
            afterrestorefunc: function () { editingRowId = undefined; },
            aftersavefunc: function () { editingRowId = undefined; }
        };

    $grid.jqGrid({
        datatype: 'local',
        ....
        editurl: 'clientArray'
    });

    // now we set or change onSelectRow callback AFTER jqGrid is created
    $grid.jqGrid('setGridParam', {
        onSelectRow: function (id) {
            if (id !== editingRowId) {
                if (typeof editingRowId !== "undefined") {
                    // save previously editing row
                    //$(this).jqGrid("saveRow", editingRowId, myInlineEditingOptions);

                    // discard changes from the previously editing row
                    $(this).jqGrid("restoreRow", editingRowId, myInlineEditingOptions);
                }
                // start inline editing. The user should save the row by pressing ENTER
                $(this).jqGrid("editRow", id, myInlineEditingOptions);
            }
        }
    });
});
```

In the above scenario it's important to mention that

1. we can set (or change) `onSelectRow` **after** the jqGrid is created.
2. It can be **only one** `onSelectRow` callback in the grid. Setting new `onSelectRow` callback *overwrite* existing one.

The last restriction can be very hard. You can't for example implements some default `onSelectRow` actions which should be done for all your grids in the project and use additional `onSelectRow` for some *additional* specific actions. It was the main reason of introducing of jQuery-like events which can be used in very close form to callbacks. The next example demonstrate the technique.

[The next demo](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/SetOnSelectDynamically1.htm) works exactly like the previous one, but it uses `jqGridSelectRow` event instead of `onSelectRow` callback. There are two important advantages of the new technique

1. one can set `jqGridSelectRow` event handler **either before jqGrid is created or after** that. If you use [jQuery.bind](http://api.jquery.com/bind/) to bind event handler, then the `<table>` element which will be converted to the grid should exist. If one uses a little more slow [jQuery.delegate](http://api.jquery.com/delegate/), [jQuery.live](http://api.jquery.com/live/) or [jQuery.on](http://api.jquery.com/on/) (the last one exists starting with jQuery 1.7) one can bind 
   the event handler at any time.
2. **one can set multiple** `jqGridSelectRow` event handler all from which will be executed *before* the only `onSelectRow` callback (if any exist). In the way you can implement some common actions in `jqGridSelectRow` event handler and can use additional `jqGridSelectRow` event handler or `onSelectRow` callback to grid specific actions. For finalization actions you can use`onSelectRow` callback.

The corresponding code looks as following

```
$(function () {
    var $grid = $("#list"),
        editingRowId,
        myInlineEditingOptions = {
            keys: true,
            oneditfunc: function (id) { editingRowId = id; },
            afterrestorefunc: function () { editingRowId = undefined; },
            aftersavefunc: function () { editingRowId = undefined; }
        };

    $grid.bind("jqGridSelectRow", function (e, id) {
        if (id !== editingRowId) {
            if (typeof editingRowId !== "undefined") {
                // save previously editing row
                //$(this).jqGrid("saveRow", editingRowId, myInlineEditingOptions);

                // discard changes from the previously editing row
                $(this).jqGrid("restoreRow", editingRowId, myInlineEditingOptions);
            }
            // start inline editing. The user should save the row by pressing ENTER
            $(this).jqGrid("editRow", id, myInlineEditingOptions);
        }
    });

    $grid.jqGrid({
        datatype: 'local',
        ....
        editurl: 'clientArray'
    });
});
```

**UPDATED**: I forgot to mention, that one can use namespacing during binding of the events. It's very helpful in more complex scenarios. If one would use `$grid.bind("jqGridSelectRow.myNamespace", ...);` then you will be able to unbind only the own events using `$grid.unbind('.myNamespace');` or `$grid.unbind('jqGridSelectRow.myNamespace');`. It will not unbind other events which has other namespace.

Answer (score 0):

I changed a little bit behavior. I wrote java script "onSelectRow" in ZF view (phtml file), like:

```
<?php $this->headScript()->captureStart() ?>
$(document).ready(function() {
    var lastSel;
    jQuery("#jqg_RentAsset").jqGrid('setGridParam', {
        onSelectRow: function(id)
        { 
            alert(id);
        }
    });
});
<?php $this->headScript()->captureEnd() ?>
```

And its working. What I needed was **"setGridParam"**
But actually this thing not working using "$grid->jqAddOnLoad($js);" in ZF controller. When I will have time, I'll investigate what else need to be done. But now I'm happy. Also, maybe there is possibility to use "$grid->setParams(array)"...
Thanks one more time. :)